Count number of observations by condition
I have a data frame as below. The values of each visit are the state numbers (eg. 1, 2, 3). People can transit between states across different visits. I want to create another dataset that contains the number of participants at each state for each visit - in a matrix with a row for each visit and a column for each state.
ID <- c(001,002,003)
Visit1 <- c(1,2,2)
Visit2 <- c(2,1,3)
Visit3 <- c(1,3,1)

df <- data.frame(ID, Visit1, Visit2, Visit3)

```
The expected outcome looks like this:

|      |State1|State2|State3|
|------|------|------|------|
|Visit1| 1    | 2    | 0    |
|Visit2| 1    | 1    | 1    |
|Visit3| 2    | 0    | 1    |


Could you include your expected output

t(table(stack(df[-1]))) should solve your problem

t(table(stack(df[-1])))

        values
ind      1 2 3
  Visit1 1 2 0
  Visit2 1 1 1
  Visit3 2 0 1


xtabs(~ind+values,transform(stack(df,-1), values = paste0('State', values)))
        values
ind      State1 State2 State3
  Visit1      1      2      0
  Visit2      1      1      1
  Visit3      2      0      1


Thank you! How do you save the final result into a dataframe?

@Jenn0804 as.data.frame.matrix(results)

do.call(rbind, lapply(df[-1], \(x) table(factor(x, levels = 1:3, labels = paste0("state",1:3)))))
#        state1 state2 state3
# Visit1      1      2      0
# Visit2      1      1      1
# Visit3      2      0      1

